# one equation three unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations, recreational-mathematics, linear-diophantine-equations

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how to solve:

```
7a+8b+9c = 1744
```

I need to know how to do this for other three unknown equations a well so the answer alone won't help me.

Thanks

Comment: What precisely do you need to solve? (One or all of the three variables?) And are you solving it over integers or reals? If it's over reals, notice that there are infinitely many solutions, you can just plug in any values for two of the three unknowns and there will be exactly one value for the remaining one.

Comment: A parametric solution is easy ... are $a,b,c$ integers ?

Comment: Hi @DonaldSplutterwit yes I need to solve for a,b and c and they are integers

Comment: as an initiation, the equation apparently has the following solutions $(0, 2, 192)
(0, 11, 184)
(0, 20, 176)
(0, 29, 168)
(0, 38, 160)
(0, 47, 152)
(0, 56, 144)
(0, 65, 136)
(0, 74, 128)
(0, 83, 120)
(0, 92, 112)
(0, 101, 104)
(0, 110, 96)
(0, 119, 88)
(0, 128, 80)
(0, 137, 72)
(0, 146, 64)
(0, 155, 56)
(0, 164, 48)
(0, 173, 40)
(0, 182, 32)
(0, 191, 24)
(0, 200, 16)
(0, 209, 8)
(0, 218, 0)$

And this is only for $a=0$ and $b,c\geq0$

Comment: There are $3060$ solutions considering $a,b,c$ positive

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi a parametrization suited to inequalities is $$ \color{magenta}{( x, 218+ 7x-9t, -7x+8t)} $$  Your profile artwork reminds me of English illustrator Frank Pape  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_C._Pap%C3%A9  especially the pen and ink for Cabell's books

Answer (score 3):

The set of integer $a,b,c$ such that $7a+8b+9c=0$ is called a lattice, on this site the tag is integer-lattices. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-lattices

Next, we find a basis for the lattice. We do this by applying column operations as multiplication on the right by elementary matrices.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
7&8&9 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&0 \\
7&9&-1 \\
-7&-8&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The outcom of doing this is that the $0$ positions in the final row $(0,0,1)$ mark the basis vectors, as columns. So, a basis is

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1&0 \\
7&9 \\
-7&-8 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
At this stage it is more convenient to write as rows: the entire lattice is parametrized as
$$ x(1,7,-7) + y ( 0,9,-8) $$
or
$$( x, 7x+9y, -7x-8y) $$

All that remains is to find a single solution for $1744$ and add these. Factoring reveals $1744 = 16 \cdot 109 = 8 \cdot 218,$  so a fixed solution is $$ ( 0, 218,0) $$

and the set of all solutions is parametrized over the integers as

$$ \color{blue}{( x, 218+ 7x+9y, -7x-8y)} $$

If I had to obey inequalities I would define $t = -y$  and write

$$ \color{magenta}{( x, 218+ 7x-9t, -7x+8t)} $$
Using these (integer) variables, the non-negative solutions of the original problem occur in the narrow triangle
$$ x \geq 0,  \; \; \; 9t-218 \leq 7x \leq 8t $$

[image]

In this dimension one may calculate a reduced basis by ordinary Gauss reduction of the binary quadratic form. The result is a different parametrization, I should use different letters

$$ \color{red}{( -u+4v, 218+ 2u+v, -u-4v)} $$

If ( I cannot tell) you have inequalities (such as all entries non-negative) the first version is probably more convenient, as the $x$ is isolated.

$$ \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Question about the matrix methodology:  Column vector $w$   with element gcd = 1. The row is $w^T.$ We have any lattice element $h \; , \; $ meaning $w^T h = 0.$  And we construct a square integer unimodular matrix $W$ with $w^T W = (1,0,0,0...,0).$   This gives $w^T =(1,0,0,...,0) W^{-1}.$ Put together with $w^T h = 0,$ we arrive at
$$ (1,0,0,0...0) W^{-1} h = 0.  $$
In turn, this means the first element in $W^{-1}h$ is zero, the others are a bunch of integers.  so
$$
W^{-1} h =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
g_2 \\
g_3 \\
\vdots \\
g_n \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Multiply on the left by $W$ for
$$
 h =
W
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
g_2 \\
g_3 \\
\vdots \\
g_n \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
If you write this out, you see it means that $h$ itself is an integer linear combination of the columns of $W$ except the first (left hand) column. We get $h = g_2 c_2 + g_3 c_3 + \cdots + g_n c_n,$
where $c_j$ is column $j$ in the square matrix $W.$ The second through final columns of $W$ really do span the lattice of integer vectors orthogonal to $w^T.$ Furthermore, $\det W = 1$ says that they are independent; the second through $n$th columns of $W$ are a basis.

Comment: The artwork on the profile is by [Minalima](https://minalima.com/) [\[ref\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3875075/one-equation-three-unknowns?noredirect=1#comment7992288_3875075). Clicking on the image will navigate there. 

Also, I read your answer, how did you find the $3\times 3$ matrix? Was it on the basis of the values found by hit and trial (using python/mathematica)?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi not random. Multiply by a sequence of elementary matrices (integer, determinant one) and number them $r_1, R_2,$ and so on. Get closer and closer to a row with a single $1$ and otherwise $0;$ Put together $R = R_1 R_2 \ldots$  because we are multiplying on the right in order to work on columns. I recommend doing this one by hand, it is relatively easy when we can easily find $1=9-8,$   then use the $1$ to cancel the other terms. Maybe I should post in my justification for this.